# Visually group rows with conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet to which I periodically add some rows. When I do so, I have a date column with the date it was added. I'd like to use conditional formatting to highlight groups of rows where the date is the same.

| Date | Foo | Bar | (Row color) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-07-13 | 4 | 0.2 | Color 1 |
| 2016-07-13 | 12 | 3.8 | Color 1 |
| 2016-07-13 | 5 | 3.1 | Color 1 |
| 2016-07-29 | 108 | 11.5 | Color 2 |
| 2016-07-29 | 25 | 6.4 | Color 2 |
| 2016-08-04 | 8 | 0.2 | Color 3 |
| 2016-08-04 | 37 | 2.3 | Color 3 |
| 2016-08-04 | 3 | 5.1 | Color 3 |

[image: Sample screenshot]

If it is possible to alternate two colors, that would be acceptable, but the *ideal system…*

- Uses a different color for each row…

  - …until a new year is reached, at which point the colors start over (if possible)
- Is not wildly bright or super-hard on the eyes
- Is reasonable to distinguish one color from the colors that surround it

I can make a simple discriminator column with `=IF(A3=A2, B2, IF(YEAR(A3)=YEAR(A2), B2+1, 0))`, but the only way I know to conveniently assign colors is with the "Color Scale," and it only colors the one cell, not its whole row.

### Knowns

- Each date will have at least 5 rows, but may have as many as 15.
- There are probably less than 15 dates per year (though making separate rules for "discriminator=1, 2, 3, …, 15" screams for better automation).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Alternating colors

If you want two alternating colors, you can set the following two rules (or only one if white is fine for the second color):

1. - Apply to range: `A2:H`
   - Custom formula is:

     ```
     =isodd(match($A2,unique($A$2:$A)))
     ```
2. Second rule (if you want another color too):

   - Apply to range: `A2:H`
   - Custom formula is:

     ```
     =iseven(match($A2,unique($A$2:$A)))
     ```

### More colors

If you want all different colors for all 15 groups, you will need to set 15 rules, like:

```
=match($A2,unique($A$2:$A))=1
=match($A2,unique($A$2:$A))=2
=match($A2,unique($A$2:$A))=3
=match($A2,unique($A$2:$A))=4
```

and so on...

Comment: This is great! I used the top formulae successfully, which was very helpful in a similar context. I see what you were going for with the second set, but I have >15 groups. It's 15 groups or so _per year._ If I wanted to reset every 15 groups, I could use `MOD()` on them, but the exact number in a year is variable. I think I can tweak what you posted to give me a set of rules without a new column, even if I can't condense it to a single rule.

Comment: For "Alternating colors", you can have a single rule (either one), first you need to color the whole sheet (except header row) with one color and then apply only one (odd or even) rule with second color.

Comment: To future self: if your data is sorted in descending order, you want `=match(…, …, -1)`

Comment: Also to future self: if your data is unsorted and you need an exact match, use `=match(…, …, 0)`

Comment: If you're trying to group things with the same value in a column, but the rows aren't ordered so these values are next to each other, try this: `=RANK($A4, ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(IFNA($A$2:$A))))` with the 'More Colors' solution

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked of course, but there's another option for visually "grouping" besides colors.  Namely a simple pivot table:

[image]

Partially collapsed to show sums:

[image]

Comment: Yep. I do those all the time. The original sheet is usually source data for a whole set of pivot tables. I've been using Kishan's thing for a bunch of spreadsheets: at work, home, hobby, and volunteering. I wanted to send them some internet points.